How to branch from a sub-branch in GitHub?
Can you branch from a sub-branch in GitHub?
I have a repository with my main branch, which I do not wish to touch. I have therefore set up another branch called dev, which will work as a ready place before the code is pushed to main.
However, I can not seem to figure out how to do this or if this it even possible with GitHub.
Could somebody enlighten me?
I have tried to use GitHub, but I'm only able to create branches from main.
If possible I would like to do it through the user interface.
Illustration of the branches

A couple things to note: There is no such thing as a "sub-branch". Branches are labels which point to a commit. Commits point to other commits, their parent(s). Why do you wish to limit creating branches from main?

How would one then setup a make a "sub-branch"?
We are a group working on the same project, but It would be stupid for all of us to commit and work with the same repository it's live. Therefore we need a "staging" branch where we commit our developments to.

I'm confused what you're stuck on. What's wrong with creating branches off develop?

I want to create a branch of "Dev" . However is there a way to make sure that branches made from "Dev" as a default push to "Dev" and not "Main".

There's no "sub-branch" in GitHub, but you can use the UI to create a new branch from any other existing branch.

Go to the "Branches" page at https://github.com/USER/REPO/branches
Click on New branch button
Fill the New branch name field
Choose the Source, the branch your new branch will be created based on, in this case, the "dev" branch.

For example, if you create the branch "bugfix" from the branch "dev" which was created from the branch "main", you can get something like the following situation:
main --- A --- B --- C --- D
                \
dev              \--- E --- F --- G --- H
                             \
bugfix                        \--- I --- J --- K --- L


Creating a new branch from an existing branch, create only a copy of that branch, as far as I understand.
Do you know if its possible to create through Git where it would keep the relationship between the branches?

There's no difference between using the Git console command or the GitHub UI. Branches keep the relationship like in the example I just added in the answer.

Do you know if then is there a way to display the relationship between branches in Github, after they have been created?

There's no info saying from where a branch was based.
